# How I can upload file in django, and access to the file content?

Tags: python, django

I tried this code but it doesn't work, I tried to add files from admin panel it works but when I create a new form and selected file, but it doesn't submitted  it shows "This field is required.", this is my code any help:

```
views:
    class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = Post
        #fields = ['title', 'content', 'XMLcontent']
        template_name = 'blog/new_post.html'
        form_class = PostCreateForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('new_post')

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.author = self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form)

    models:
    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        content = models.TextField()
        XMLcontent = models.FileField()
        post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        rate = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
        post_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def display_text_file(self):
            with open(self.XMLcontent.path) as fp:
                return fp.read().replace('\n', '<br>')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('detail', args=[self.pk])

    forms:
    class PostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
          title = forms.CharField(label='title ')
          content = forms.CharField(label='content ', widget=forms.Textarea)
          XMLcontent = forms.FileField(label='structured content ')
          class Meta:
              model = Post
              fields = ['title', 'content', 'XMLcontent']
```

Comment: Hi @Antonio! Did you have an error code somewhere? If so, could you please add it by updating your question, so the community will better be able to help you?

Comment: thank u @toshiro92 this is my first question.^_^